# Is it legal to delete copy/move functions of a Coroutine in C++20 and instantiate it?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, coroutine, c++-coroutine

I have noticed that the following code is both accepted by [MSVC and GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/6bbszroEq) (shortened TLDR version below):

```
template<typename T>
struct Generator {
    struct promise_type {
        std::suspend_always initial_suspend() {
            return {};
        }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept {
            return {};
        }
        auto get_return_object() {
            return Generator{ std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this) };
        }

        std::suspend_always yield_value(T value) {
            current_value = value;
            return {};
        }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() {
            std::exit(1);
        }

        T current_value;
    };
    
    Generator(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h): coro(h) {}                

    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> coro;
    
    ~Generator() {
        if (coro) coro.destroy();
    }
    Generator(const Generator&)              = delete;
    Generator& operator = (const Generator&) = delete;
    Generator(Generator&&)                   = delete;
    Generator& operator = (Generator&&)      = delete;

    T operator()() {
        coro.resume();
        return coro.promise().current_value;
    }

};

Generator<int> getNext() {
    int value = 0;
    while (true) {
        co_yield value;
        value++;
    }
}

int main() {
    Generator<int> gen = getNext();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) {
        int val = gen();
        std::cout << "val: " << val << std::endl;
    }
    
}
```

TLDR version:

```
template<typename T>
struct Generator {
    struct promise_type {
        //...
    };
    
    //...
    
    Generator(const Generator&)              = delete;
    Generator& operator = (const Generator&) = delete;
    Generator(Generator&&)                   = delete;
    Generator& operator = (Generator&&)      = delete;

    //...

};

Generator<int> getNext() {
    //...
}

int main() {
    Generator<int> gen = getNext();
    //...
}
```

I wonder however if this is allowed by the C++20 Standard. Normally, a type can not be retrieved by a function if the copy and move functions are deleted:

```
struct MyType
{
    MyType() {}

    MyType(const MyType&)              = delete;
    MyType& operator = (const MyType&) = delete;
    MyType(MyType&&)                   = delete;
    MyType& operator = (MyType&&)      = delete;
};

MyType generateType()
{
    MyType val;
    return val; // <--- Compile Error
}
```

At first glance this line seems to also use the deleted functions: `Generator<int> gen = getNext();`

Is this allowed for coroutines? If yes, which part of the standard allows it?

Comment: `Generator<int> gen = getNext()` does not involve any of the deleted functions (assuming that `Generator` instance inside of this function is created using `Generator(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h)` constructor).

Comment: Since C++17, there is mandatory copy elision, so `Generator<int> gen = getNext()` construct "in-place", without move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the `Generator` object is retrieved through a call to `get_return_object()`, which returns a prvalue. This, as of C++17, requires mandatory copy elision. See cppreference.com:

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible:

> In a return statement, when the operand is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type: